# Class synonyms over inheritance: Performance?

Tags: java, performance, optimization

i have a class with a long name, for example `DatabaseHelper`.
Now i want to shorten this name.

1) I could rename the class, then i would have, what i want.

2) I could create a synoym class: `class Db extends DatabaseHelper`:
The body here would be empty.

Cause of the quality standards here, the question in coding style

```
class DatabaseHelper
{
  //some methods
}
```

and now the synonym class

```
class Db extends DatabaseHelper
{
  //empty body
}
```

So my question is: Get i performance problems, if i do that like 2),
or would 1) equal 2) on the performance dimension?

Comment: Forget performance. This is just a bad thing to do. Give your classes better names in the first place.

Comment: `DatabaseHelper` is not a long name.... Db is an incredibly short name that does not give the user any value (they have no idea what it does)

Comment: yes you are both right, but thats not my question^^
But its a good design hint not doing somethin like that.
But i want to know if i do that, what the compiler will do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The performance might get worse in some places because *Class Hierarchy Analysis* will see that there are two possible classes and give up. There are other optimizations and all the stuff is far too complicated, but if you want to understand it, read this [lengthy explanation](https://shipilev.net/blog/2015/black-magic-method-dispatch/). If not, then read a part of it to see how complicated it can get.

Given that you're dealing with databases, i.e., operations somewhere at a millisecond scale, you *won't be able to measure* your performance loss somewhere at the nanosecond scale. So forget it.

Note that `DatabaseHelper` is by no means a long name. It's pretty short and pretty unhelpful (it could be clearer). Note that `Db` might be a good shortcut for `Database`, but not for `DatabaseHelper`. Not `DbH` would do (pretty everyone can guess, what "Db" means, but with "DbH", pretty nobody can; anyway, names which needn't be guessed are better).

**Please note that there are no type synonyms in Java and can not be.** By subclassing, you get a new class which is interoperable only in one direction. *So do not do it!*

Also note that performance in Java is much more complicated than expected. Choosing good algorithms and data structures matters a lot, but most details are irrelevant (this site is full of questions like "is A faster than B" and the typical correct answer is "forget it").